# Install Rakudo on termux/android

Tags: raku, termux, rakudo, rakudo-star

Hi everyone I need help how to install rakudo in termux aarch64

I have tried different ways and got different errors, first try:

[image]

Second try:

[image]

Comment: This question is being discussed on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/410819)

Comment: It is possible to do it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69091046/installing-rakudo-on-termux-on-android-in-arm-processor-architecture/69247911#69247911

Answer (score 6):

**Update** See https://borg.moe/building-rakudo-perl-6-on-termux.html

I don't know Termux but thought the following was better than no answer. Perhaps you already know the following, in which case this is just for later readers; if you actually know *more*, please edit your question and add what else you know.

---

The closest target for standard Rakudo packages is GNU+Linux, but Termux's own doc emphasizes its *differences* from Linux. The bottom line is you're going to have to manually patch/compile/build to install on Termux.

The termux user `its-pointless` claimed they *manually* built Rakudo, for aarch64, in 2018 and again in 2019, and, per a screenshot in [a recent (2021) tweet](https://twitter.com/ernestoxbox/status/1422068011872133123), did so again for a 2020.05 package, at least for the MoarVM backend.

Perhaps you and/or others can use the existing packages and/or more recent ones and/or build on their success.

## Googling

I don't know Termux so don't know where one would look for a more recent package beyond google.

A [google for `termux raku OR perl6 OR "perl 6"`](https://www.google.com/search?q=termux+raku+OR+perl6+OR+%22perl+6%22) yields some matches.

That's how I discovered some open Raku issues related to Termux, and many comments by `its-pointless` in one of them, culminating in 2018 with [this comment](https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/issues/1324#issuecomment-378820597), and another comment leading to [info for installing a 2019 moarvm on termux/aarch64](https://github.com/its-pointless/its-pointless.github.io/blob/0d6340f2e7db3be83d949f0411407073cd1b7710/files/24/dists/termux/extras/binary-aarch64/Packages#L916-L929) and then [a 2019 Rakudo atop that](https://github.com/its-pointless/its-pointless.github.io/blob/0d6340f2e7db3be83d949f0411407073cd1b7710/files/24/dists/termux/extras/binary-aarch64/Packages#L1472-L1485) (which depends on moarvm).

## How hard are you willing to try?

I personally don't have any of the distro related skills needed to be able to help you to get Rakudo built. But it seems several folk managed to get a working Rakudo with the help of `its-pointless`. So perhaps you will be able to do so too.

If you have [patience](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the+patience+of+job%22), like the folk in the issue I linked, there might be other Rakoons capable and willing to try to help you get Rakudo building on your system.

## Termux

While Termux is a Linux, it's not a GNU+Linux. From ["Differences from Linux"](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Differences_from_Linux), with my added **emphasis**:

> Termux does not follow [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) unlike majority of Linux distributions. You cannot find directories like /bin, /etc, /usr, /tmp and others at the usual locations. Thus, **all programs must be patched and recompiled to meet requirements of the Termux environment** otherwise they will not be able to find their configuration files or other data.

I presume the packages `its-pointless` built include the requisite patching, at least as of 2019.

## Your first try

> `[CRIT] No /etc/os-release found. Are you sure you're on a sane GNU+Linux distribution?`

A [google for "/etc/os-release"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%2Fetc%2Fos-release) reveals:

> /etc/os-release
>
> - It relieves application developers who just want to know the distribution they are running on to check for a multitude of individual release files.
> - It provides both a "pretty" name (i.e. one to show to the user), and machine parsable version/OS identifiers (i.e. for use in build systems).

I think a takeaway from your first try is that the build systems of the "official" Rakudo packages presume that a Linux is a GNU+Linux. Termux isn't. So that approach isn't going to work.

Somehow you got past the problem reported in the first try. What did you do?

## Second try

At a guess your second try is using the same packages. So it's not going to work.

> `n't exec "./try": Permission denied at build/probe.pm line 935. Unable to run probe, so something is badly wrong ...`.

Again, I think the root problem is that you're trying to install a package that presumes a GNU+Linux, which won't work because Termux isn't a GNU+Linux.