# Installing Rakudo on Android with ARM processor architecture

Tags: raku, termux, rakudo

I am trying to install Rakudo on my Android with armv7l processor architecture using Termux.

I tried compiling from source, but it didn't work. Then someone pointed out  the Termux user [its-pointless](https://github.com/its-pointless/) and his package for this, but that package does not work on my phone.

How can I run Raku on my phone while it is offline? I'm open to solutions not using Termux.

Termux on SSH results:
[image: Termux on SSH]

```
u0_a74@localhost ~/rakudo [100]> pkg show rakudo -a
```

> Package: rakudo Version: 2020.05 Maintainer: Termux members @termux
> Installed-Size: 37.7 MB Depends: moarvm Homepage: https://rakudo.org
> Download-Size: 5062 kB APT-Manual-Installed: yes APT-Sources:
> https://its-pointless.github.io/files/24 termux/extras arm Packages
> Description: Perl 6 implementation on top of Moar virtual machine
>
> Package: rakudo Version: 2020.01-1 Maintainer: Fredrik Fornwall
> @fornwall Installed-Size: 93.1 MB Depends: moarvm Homepage:
> https://rakudo.org Download-Size: 10.9 MB APT-Sources:
> https://its-pointless.github.io/files/24 termux/extras arm Packages
> Description: Perl 6 implementation on top of Moar virtual machine

```
u0_a74@localhost ~/rakudo> raku
```

> CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE "raku": cannot locate symbol "ffi_type_double"
> referenced by "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/libmoar.so"...

```
u0_a74@localhost ~/rakudo> raku --version
```

> CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE "raku": cannot locate symbol "ffi_type_double"
> referenced by "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/libmoar.so"...

```
u0_a74@localhost ~/rakudo> raku --help
```

> CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE "raku": cannot locate symbol "ffi_type_double"
> referenced by "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/libmoar.so"...

```
u0_a74@localhost ~/rakudo> uname -a
```

> Linux localhost 3.4.42-g3d041de #1 SMP PREEMPT Sat Dec 24 19:56:29 PST
> 2016 armv7l Android

Comment: There's a symbol it can't find. Have you tried installing the corresponding package?

Comment: @jjmerelo im not sure if i can find the exactly corresponding package easily. i supose it is the moarvm package. which gets installed when i install the Rakudo package. because it depends on it. i guess this whole package it is just broken. at least on my phone

Comment: but that package needs another dynamic library, that you might need to install in advance, apparently. That library should provide ffi_type_double.

Comment: it looks like that dynamic library is the libmoar.so which is probably the MoarVM itself

Comment: http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/doc/libffi-dev/html/Primitive-Types.html

Comment: "it looks like that dynamic library is the libmoar.so" That doesn't make sense. The error message says "cannot locate symbol "ffi_type_double" referenced by "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/libmoar.so". The latter can't be missing because the error message provides its location! And it says libmoar.so referenced the symbol "ffi_type_double". *That symbol* is what can't be located by the system. And a google for *that* suggests it's part of a package related to libffi. So it sounds like you need to find the right package related to libffi and correctly install it to make progress.

Comment: Your Q mentions "termux/extras arm". Googling for that led to https://github.com/its-pointless/its-pointless.github.io/blob/master/files/24/dists/termux/extras/binary-arm/Packages. Searching that for moar led to various packages. The 2020.05 one says "Breaks: libtommath-dev, libtommath ... Depends: libuv, libandroid-support, libffi ... Replaces: libtommath-dev, libtommath". So, sounds like you need libuv, libandroid-support, and libffi packages, and any packages they depend on (if any) recursively. (And sounds like it'll replace/break any libtommath-dev, libtommath you already have installed.)

Comment: theses libuv, libandroid-support, libffi packages are installed on my phone. should i reinstall?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Sp0bWLd

Comment: if i remove the package libffi. many packages on my system will be removed

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/EsJ1RhG

Comment: I wouldn't remove packages if it were me. I'd try to understand why the reference to the symbol "ffi_type_double" by the moarvm.so you've got installed is failing to connect with what is presumably a matching symbol in the libffi package that's already installed. Presumably that's due to how the libffi gets dynamically linked (or not). Beyond that I'm outta ideas. (I know little about this kind of stuff beyond what I wrote in my answer to the other termux question posted here under the [raku] tag.) Patience, waiting for other comments, and praying to the goddess of tech, is all I can suggest.

Comment: yeah that looks like a safer option i will try to find out that first before anything radical. maybe it will work now. help us goddess of tech

Comment: i think progress is being made.
running the command. grep -Rn ffi_type_double
grep finded that the files /usr/lib/libffi.so and /usr/lib/libmoar.so does match with that string. so i think the type is there on those files.
https://imgur.com/a/ab7IBdv

Comment: See https://borg.moe/building-rakudo-perl-6-on-termux.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does it have to be on Termux? I have successfully installed Raku on Android via UserLand, using Debian SSH. `sudo apt-get install rakudo` works.